# Google Analytics API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-analytics

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve data from my own Google Analytics account in an ASP application. Every example I found involves requesting access to a user's Analytics account via OAuth, which is not what I want. All I need is to be able to query data from my own account in C#.NET or VB.NET.

What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: How do you intend your application to gain access to your Google Analytics account, if not via OAuth?

Comment: Oh there's no issue with using OAuth if that's the method available to access my account data. I would just like to know of a way to do so, using OAuth or not, to be able to retrieve that Analytics data in .NET without having to change any stored access tokens overtime.

Answer (score 0):

You may use YQL tables for Google Analytics.

https://github.com/yql/yql-tables/blob/master/google/google.analytics.xml